# How to snap NURBS Surface Curve to vertex-es?

Tags: snapping, nurbs-surface

I've noticed strange difference between how snapping work for NURBS Curve's and NURBS Surface Curve's - for the second, it always snap to increment, even if different snap target is selected.

I mean, if you try to use snapping to vertexes(or any other snapping target):

[image: "snap to" settings]

With snapping to vertex enabled in editing mode, if will try to move point of NURBS Curve, then it will snap to nearest vertex under cursor:

[image: NURBS Curve snapping]

But if i try to move points of NURBS Surface Curve, then it will always try to snap only to increment, not caring what "snap to" target is really selected:

[image: NURBS Surface Curve snapping]

Tried on Blender 2.79, 2.83, 2.90 - same behaviour. Is this a bug? Or there is a setting somewhere, that allows NURBS Surface Curve's to snap to something other than "increment"?

Comment: Hello :). It's not a bug, full snapping is just not yet implemented. NURBS workflow really needs some love. You can suggest improvements on https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect